# How to save / reload a custom array to a plist

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, plist

I'm loading in data from an sqlite database, storing the values i load from there in the instance variables of a custom class, and then adding this class to a mutable array, which i'm then assigning to the instance variable of my view controller, for use in a tableview.

I would, though, like to save this array into a .plist file in the documents directory on the app's first run, so that i can retrieve the whole object from there on load, rather than pulling all 214 items from the database.

Is this approach a better option? if so, could someone please help provide me with some code that will allow me to save an array of my custom classes as a .plist file? I've come across a lot of sample code on the web, but none of it works correctly.

I'd like to:

- Check for the existence of the my_data.plist file.
- If it exists, read it in as the array.
- If it doesn't, read the data from the sqlite db into an array.
- save this data to a .plist so that it can be read in faster later.

Thanks guys, appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: In what way didn't the sample code you run work correctly? What was the code? What happened when you ran it?

Answer (score 3):

It will probably be faster to just get the values from your database on launch.  There will almost definitely be more cost to parse a plist containing these values than to just get them all from the database, unless the query you have to use to get them from the database is really slow.

Note also that once you're saving these objects to a plist on disk, you're actually going to be hurting performance of your program because you'll be writing your objects to disk twice and reading them from disk twice.  You'll also be introducing opportunities for discrepancies between the plist and the database in the event of a bug or a crash.

That said, the only way to prove this to yourself may be to implement and profile both options, and compare actual numbers.  Check out @occulus's link, above, for instructions how to read and write a plist.  To profile your app, try using [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/AboutTracing/AboutTracing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH9-SW1)

Comment: Thankyou, i'll take a look at the link and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

When I google for "nsarray writetofile custom object" (no quotes) and click on the first link in the results, I find a really useful page.

For the record, it's this:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/240775-saving-nsarray-of-custom-objects.html